# Facebook FQL query returns empty result set when LIMIT is used with DESC order

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

You can try this using the Graph API Explorer:

```
SELECT post_id, id, fromid, time, text, user_likes, likes FROM comment WHERE post_id ='126757470715601_530905090300835' AND time < '1366318653' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 30
```

This will return an empty result set. BUT if I remove DESC from the query, it will return 30 results.

```
SELECT post_id, id, fromid, time, text, user_likes, likes FROM comment WHERE post_id ='126757470715601_530905090300835' AND time < '1366318653' ORDER BY time LIMIT 30
```

So adding DESC to the order by somehow changed the way LIMIT behaves. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The time is within range. Sorry by my wrong calculation before. What you can do is increase the comment number to huge value, such as LIMIT 150, because there's may be a lot of comments is_privacy='0' around 30 items.

Comment: But 1366406750 is not the earliest comment. You can see this if you remove the LIMIT.

Comment: @aylz5073 the scenario still same, the query time is out of range

Comment: If you try "SELECT post_id, id, fromid, time, text, user_likes, likes FROM comment WHERE post_id ='126757470715601_530905090300835' ORDER BY time DESC", you can see that the latest comment is 1366406750. And 1366300956 (earliest) <= 1366318653 (target) <= 1366406750 (latest). It should have given me 30 comments before 1366318653, but it didn't.

Comment: @aylz5073 Sorry about that. However, what you can do is increase the comment number to huge value, such as LIMIT 150, because there's may be a lot of comments is_privacy='0' around 30 items.

Comment: The problem seems to be that LIMIT is applied before 'time < X'. For example, a simple test is to try ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5. To get the next 5 results, I have to use AND TIME < (time of 5th latest comment) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10. Because the first 5 results are not visible. Have you encountered this situation before? Increasing the limit is a work-around, but some posts have well over 1000 comments.

Comment: @aylz5073 Yeah, this problem is exist when i query newsfeed from stream table before, you can visit https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28542/discussion-between-aylz5073-and-)